# find and Calculate centroid within polygon either in ArcMap or in MapInfo

Tags: arcmap, mapinfo

How can I calculate single/multiple centroid(point) within polygon either in ArcMap or in MapInfo. Both object(point, polygon) are in different layers.

Comment: ET GeoWizards Polygons to Points has many option (better than arcgis) http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/et_geowizards_userguide.htm see Polygon to Point

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change your objects into points (the centroid) you can use this statement thru the MapBasic window in MapInfo Professional:

```
Update MY_TABLE Set OBJ = Centroid(OBJ)
```

Do remember to do this on a copy of your data file as your original spatial objects will be replaced with the point!

Comment: "You need to specify _Centroid(obj)_ in the most recent version on Mapinfo. Using  the recommended _Centroid()_ will produce an error." (This was a comment from an anonymous user, who tried to edit the post)

Comment: Thanks, yeah I missed the OBJ parameter to the Centroid() function. I have edited the answer to show the right syntax

Answer (score 4):

This is an old answer but here are my two cents using Arcpy.

There is a great script from ESRI about creating a point layer of centroids here: http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/41027.

However, if the need is to get the centroid *or* a point that falls within a polygon, I wrote a little guess-and-check script that will find a point that is within the feature. (I found this necessary because "Feature to Point" tool requires an advanced license.)
Here `fc` is a polygon featureclass.

```
import arcpy
import random 
random.seed()

pth = "E:/out_path/"
out_file_name = "output_point_file"
arcpy.env.workspace = pth

fc = "PolygonLayer.shp"
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@TRUECENTROID","SHAPE@"])
ptGeomList = []

cent = arcpy.Point()
for feat in cursor:

    cent.X = feat[0][0]
    cent.Y = feat[0][1]
    outside = not feat[1].contains(cent)

    cnt = 0

    while outside:
        if cnt == 1000:
            print "Tried 1000 times, feature might be too small"
            break
        cnt += 1

        xmin = feat[1].extent.XMin
        xmax = feat[1].extent.XMax
        ymin = feat[1].extent.YMin
        ymax = feat[1].extent.YMax
        # Create random numbers within the extent
        #   of the parent feature
        newX = random.random() * (xmax - xmin) + xmin 
        newY = random.random() * (ymax - ymin) + ymin
        cent.X = newX; cent.Y = newY 
        # Then check to see if this is within
        outside = not feat[1].contains(cent)

    ptGeomList.append(arcpy.PointGeometry(cent))

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(ptGeomList, out_file_name)
```

Note that this may not work well for small polygons, so I've written this to break after 1,000 attempts at finding a point within the polygon.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I need to push the attribute table of the fc into the point geometry. Was thinking I could write the values to a CSV and then manipulate that way.

Answer (score 2):

In Arc Map you can use the "Feature to Point" tool under Data Management Tools to generate points at the Centroid of each feature. Make sure to leave the Inside option unchecked (some polygons may have centroids outside of the input polygon.

Hope This Helps

Answer (score 2):

In Mapinfo you can add fields to a table, then use the update column feature to populate those fields with CentroidX(OBJ) and CentroidY(OBJ)

Comment: ...and then use Table > Create Points to create the points.